# Excel formatting from Access works every other time (object variable/with block not set)

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I have an on click sub routine that exports two tables to excel.
I have then recorded an excel macro and copied the code to access to format the worksheet accordingly.

My problem is that every other time i run the code i get this error:
"Run-time error '91': Object variable or with block variable not set"

This occurs at this point of my code:

```
        With .ActiveSheet
            .Range("B" & .Cells.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Activate
        End With

        With ActiveCell
        '~~~~~~~~ERROR OCCURS HERE~~~~~~~~~~~~
            .formula = "=SUM(B2:" & ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Address & ")" 
        '~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
            .Font.Bold = True
        End With
```

The range I am trying to SUM is dynamic which is why I offset the cell up 1 in the formula,
I have tried:

```
    .formula = "=SUM(B2:B3)"
```

but this gives the same error.

The full code is below, I have been receiving this error from the first line under the comment 'Excel Worksheet Formatting' and have been getting round it by adding With blocks into the code, but cannot get around the .formula= line.

I am really stuck with this, any help would be greatly appreciated

Full Code:

```
    Private Sub cmdExport_Click()

    Dim xl As Excel.Application
    Dim wb As Object
    Dim todaysDate As String
    Dim fd As FileDialog
    Dim FolderChosen As Integer

    DoCmd.SetWarnings False

    todaysDate = Replace(Date, "/", "")

    Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

    FolderChosen = fd.Show

    If FolderChosen <> -1 Then
        MsgBox ("Export Cancelled")
    Else

    CurrentDb.QueryDefs("plates_sold").SQL = "SELECT plates.Plate, plates.                 [Price In], plates.[Price Out], (plates.[Price Out] - plates.[Price In]) AS Income, dbo_Sales.[Date Deposit Rec] AS [Deposit Paid], dbo_Sales.[Comm By Who] AS [Sold By] " & _
                                         "FROM plates INNER JOIN dbo_Sales ON plates.Plate = dbo_Sales.Plate " & _
                                         "WHERE plates.[Plate Status] = 'F' AND dbo_Sales.[Date Deposit Rec] IS NOT NULL"

DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputQuery, "plates_sold", "Excel Workbook (*.xlsx)", fd.SelectedItems(1) & "/" & Me.Text24.Value & "_Recovery_" & todaysDate & ".xlsx"
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, "plates_stock", fd.SelectedItems(1) & "/" & Me.Text24.Value & "_Recovery_" & todaysDate & ".xlsx"

Set xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set wb = xl.Workbooks.Open(fd.SelectedItems(1) & "/" & Me.Text24.Value & "_Recovery_" & todaysDate & ".xlsx")
xl.DisplayAlerts = False
xl.Visible = True

'========================================== Excel Worksheet Formatting ==========================================
    With wb
        .Sheets("plates_stock").Select
        .ActiveSheet.Columns("A:G").Cut
        .Sheets("plates_sold").Select
        .Sheets(1).Name = Me.Text24.Value & " Recovery"
        .ActiveSheet.Range("I1").Select
        .ActiveSheet.Paste
        .Sheets("plates_stock").Delete

        With .ActiveSheet.Range("I1:O1")
            .Font.Bold = True
            .Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
            .Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
            With .Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
                .LineStyle = xlContinuous
                .ColorIndex = 0
                .TintAndShade = 0
                .Weight = xlThin
            End With
            With .Borders(xlEdgeTop)
                .LineStyle = xlContinuous
                .ColorIndex = 0
                .TintAndShade = 0
                .Weight = xlThin
            End With
            With .Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
                .LineStyle = xlContinuous
                .ColorIndex = 0
                .TintAndShade = 0
                .Weight = xlThin
            End With
            With .Borders(xlEdgeRight)
                .LineStyle = xlContinuous
                .ColorIndex = 0
                .TintAndShade = 0
                .Weight = xlThin
            End With
            With .Borders(xlInsideVertical)
                .LineStyle = xlContinuous
                .ColorIndex = 0
                .TintAndShade = 0
                .Weight = xlThin
            End With
            With .Borders(xlInsideHorizontal)
                .LineStyle = xlContinuous
                .ColorIndex = 0
                .TintAndShade = 0
                .Weight = xlThin
            End With

            With .Interior
                .Pattern = xlSolid
                .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                .Color = 11711154
                .TintAndShade = 0
                .PatternTintAndShade = 0
            End With

        End With

        'format stock prices to price
        With .ActiveSheet
            .Range(.Range("K2:L2"), .Range("K2:L2").End(xlDown)).NumberFormat = "$#,##0.00"
        End With

        'sold total price in
        With .ActiveSheet
            .Range("B2").Select
        End With
        With .ActiveSheet
            .Range("B" & .Cells.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Activate
        End With

    '~~~~~~~~~~~WITH BLOCK NOT SET~~~~~~~~~~~

        With ActiveCell
            .formula = "=SUM(B2:" & ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Address & ")"
            .Font.Bold = True
        End With

    '~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

        'sold total price out
        Range("C2").Select
        ActiveCell.End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Select
        ActiveCell.formula = "=SUM(C2:" & ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Address & ")"
        ActiveCell.Font.Bold = True

        'sold total income
        Range("D2").Select
        ActiveCell.End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Select
        ActiveCell.formula = "=SUM(D2:" & ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Address & ")"
        ActiveCell.Font.Bold = True

        'stock total price in
        Range("K2").Select
        ActiveCell.End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Select
        ActiveCell.formula = "=SUM(K2:" & ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Address & ")"
        ActiveCell.Font.Bold = True

        'Insert ROS %
        Range("C2").End(xlDown).Offset(2, 0).Select
        ActiveCell.Value = "ROS"
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
        ActiveCell.formula = "=(" & ActiveCell.Offset(-2, 0).Address & "/" & ActiveCell.Offset(-2, -1).Address & ")"
        ActiveCell.NumberFormat = "0.00%"
        ActiveCell.Font.Bold = True

        'Insert Total Spent
        ActiveCell.Offset(3, -1).Select
        ActiveCell.Value = "Total Spent"
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
        ActiveCell.formula = "=(" & ActiveCell.Offset(-5, -2).Address & "+" & Range("K2").End(xlDown).Address & ")"
        ActiveCell.NumberFormat = "$#,##0.00"
        ActiveCell.Font.Bold = True

        'Insert Recovery %
        ActiveCell.Offset(-2, -1).Select
        ActiveCell.Value = "Recovery"
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
        ActiveCell.formula = "=(" & ActiveCell.Offset(-3, 0).Address & "/" & ActiveCell.Offset(2, 0).Address & ")"
        ActiveCell.NumberFormat = "0.00%"
        ActiveCell.Font.Bold = True

        'autofit columns
        Columns("A:A").EntireColumn.AutoFit
        Columns("B:B").EntireColumn.AutoFit
        Columns("C:C").EntireColumn.AutoFit
        Columns("D:D").EntireColumn.AutoFit
        Columns("E:E").EntireColumn.AutoFit
        Columns("F:F").EntireColumn.AutoFit
        Columns("I:I").EntireColumn.AutoFit
        Columns("J:J").EntireColumn.AutoFit
        Columns("K:K").EntireColumn.AutoFit
        Columns("L:L").EntireColumn.AutoFit
        Columns("M:M").EntireColumn.AutoFit
        Columns("N:N").EntireColumn.AutoFit
        Columns("O:O").EntireColumn.AutoFit

        Range("A1").Select

    End With
'======================================================================================================

wb.Save
Set xl = Nothing

    End If

    DoCmd.SetWarnings True

    End Sub
```

Comment: **All** your `ActiveCell`, `Range`, and `Column` calls should be prefixed with a `.` to refer them back to `xl`. It's also really inefficient to select cells just to manipulate them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No guarantees I got all the offsets correct, but this should give you an idea of how to manipulate the cells without selecting them:

```
Private Sub cmdExport_Click()

    Dim xl                    As Excel.Application
    Dim wb                    As Object
    Dim todaysDate            As String
    Dim fd                    As FileDialog
    Dim FolderChosen          As Integer

    DoCmd.SetWarnings False

    todaysDate = Replace(Date, "/", "")

    Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

    FolderChosen = fd.Show

    If FolderChosen <> -1 Then
        MsgBox ("Export Cancelled")
    Else

        CurrentDb.QueryDefs("plates_sold").Sql = "SELECT plates.Plate, plates.[Price In], plates.[Price Out], (plates.[Price Out] - plates.[Price In]) AS Income, dbo_Sales.[Date Deposit Rec] AS [Deposit Paid], dbo_Sales.[Comm By Who] AS [Sold By] " & _
                                                 "FROM plates INNER JOIN dbo_Sales ON plates.Plate = dbo_Sales.Plate " & _
                                                 "WHERE plates.[Plate Status] = 'F' AND dbo_Sales.[Date Deposit Rec] IS NOT NULL"

        DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputQuery, "plates_sold", "Excel Workbook (*.xlsx)", fd.SelectedItems(1) & "/" & Me.Text24.Value & "_Recovery_" & todaysDate & ".xlsx"
        DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, "plates_stock", fd.SelectedItems(1) & "/" & Me.Text24.Value & "_Recovery_" & todaysDate & ".xlsx"

        Set xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
        Set wb = xl.Workbooks.Open(fd.SelectedItems(1) & "/" & Me.Text24.Value & "_Recovery_" & todaysDate & ".xlsx")
        xl.DisplayAlerts = False
        xl.Visible = True

        '========================================== Excel Worksheet Formatting ==========================================
        With wb
            .Sheets("plates_stock").Columns("A:G").Cut Destination:=.Sheets("plates_sold").Range("I1")
            .Sheets("plates_sold").Select
            .Sheets(1).Name = Me.Text24.Value & " Recovery"
            .Sheets("plates_stock").Delete

            With .ActiveSheet.Range("I1:O1")
                .Font.Bold = True
                With .Borders
                    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
                    .ColorIndex = 0
                    .TintAndShade = 0
                    .Weight = xlThin
                End With

                With .Interior
                    .Pattern = xlSolid
                    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                    .Color = 11711154
                    .TintAndShade = 0
                    .PatternTintAndShade = 0
                End With

            End With

            'format stock prices to price
            With .ActiveSheet
                .Range(.Range("K2:L2"), .Range("K2:L2").End(xlDown)).NumberFormat = "$#,##0.00"
                With .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(, 3)
                    .FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R2C:R[-1]C)"
                    .Font.Bold = True
                End With
                '~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

                'stock total price in
                With .Range("K2").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0)
                    .FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R2C:R[-1]C)"
                    .Font.Bold = True
                End With

                'Insert ROS %
                With .Range("C2").End(xlDown).Offset(2, 0)
                    .Value2 = "ROS"
                    With .Offset(0, 1)
                        .FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-2]C/R[-2]C[-1]"
                        .NumberFormat = "0.00%"
                        .Font.Bold = True
                    End With
                    'Insert Total Spent
                    With .Offset(3, 0)
                        .Value2 = "Total Spent"
                        With .Offset(0, 1)
                            .FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-5]C[-2]+" & .Range("K2").End(xlDown).Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1)
                            .NumberFormat = "$#,##0.00"
                            .Font.Bold = True
                        End With
                    End With
                    'Insert Recovery %
                    With .Offset(1, 0)
                        .Value2 = "Recovery"
                        With .Offset(0, 1)
                            .FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-3]C/R[2]C"
                            .NumberFormat = "0.00%"
                            .Font.Bold = True
                        End With
                    End With
                End With
                'autofit columns
                .Columns("A:F").EntireColumn.AutoFit
                .Columns("I:O").EntireColumn.AutoFit
            End With

        End With
        '======================================================================================================

        wb.Save
        Set xl = Nothing

    End If

    DoCmd.SetWarnings True

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you this is absolutely brilliant, exactly what I needed.
I had just copied a recorded macro from excel so that is why the .selects where there but now that I think about it of course they are not needed.
Thanks again!